# Apache caching old configuration?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a standard Apache/2.4.7 setup on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. It has a few virtual hosts.

I changed from an old config for this virtual host to a new one by `a2ensite` the new and `a2dissite` the old. The contents aren't important but I'll include them for completeness:

`old-thing.conf` did a redirect

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName       thing.mysite.com
  Redirect permanent / http://otherthing.mysite.com/
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

`new-thing.conf` does a reverse proxy

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
  ServerName       thing.mysite.com
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
   ProxyPass        / http://123.123.123:80/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://123.123.123:80/
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted Apache. When I run `apachectl -S` I see:

```
port 80 namevhost thing.mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/new-thing.conf:1)
```

This tells me that Apache is using the new configuration file. But when I fetch the domain I see the redirect as it was specified in `old-thing.conf`.

```
$ curl -v http://thing.mysite.com
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: thing.mysite.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 18:36:34 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< Location: http://thing.mysite.com/
< Content-Length: 329
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
< etc...
```

I am puzzled. The old config is long gone. I have restarted Apache and there is no cache in the client as I'm using curl. There is another test virtualhost (shown by `apache -S`) which is also not recognised. Something weird is going on. Could it somehow be caching the old config?

I do not understand how it can be using the old configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you "gracefully" restart apache?  Sometimes it doesn't really reconfigure everything when you do that.

Comment: I did a full (non-graceful) restart. Are you suggesting that the internal configuration could be out of sync with tat shown by `apachectl -S`?

Comment: Try if clearing your browser cache helps.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using curl which has no cache.

Comment: No, if you did a full restart you can ignore that concern.  Seems though that you must have either a config being used you aren't expecting, or perhaps an entirely different httpd binary.  Ensure that the httpd binary you are running is the one you think it is (poke around in /proc, use lsof, etc).  Ensure that it really did get restarted (with ps).

Comment: Not your case, but for other readers : make sure your virtualhosts configuration files names end with `.conf`.